# How to center a TextView between two buttons?

Tags: android

I want to center my **TextView** between two buttons:

[image]

I take a **RelativeLayout** I don't know how is to do, below is my xml code please  guide me where make a change to do this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop ="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true">

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/but_left"
            android:layout_width = "80dp"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="&lt;"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_toLeftOf = "@+id/but_right"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/but_right"
            android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/but_left" />


        <Button
            android:id = "@id/but_right"
            android:layout_width = "80dp"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="&gt;"
            android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` Textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/but_left"
            android:layout_width = "80dp"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="hello_world"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/but_right"
            android:layout_width = "80dp"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:text="Buton2 "
            android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your **text is not bigger/longer** and just few characters are there than remove `layout_toLeftOf` and `layout_toRightOf`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/but_right"/>
```

If you think your **text will be longer** in future, use `gravity` and change width to `match_parent`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf = "@+id/but_right"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/but_right"
        android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/but_left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting width to `match_parent`  and gravity to `center`

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_toLeftOf = "@+id/but_right"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/but_right"
            android:layout_toRightOf = "@id/but_left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple layout..

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but_left"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Your Text" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 2" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```